# SQL Server: Swap two lines depending on criteria

Tags: sql, sql-server

Suppose a table named **Sales** with this data in SQL Server

```
--------------------------------------------
Id      |  Customer_Id      |  Rate  |  Pid
--------------------------------------------
180     |  374              |  1     |  A01
277     |  374              |  0     |  NULL
346     |  785              |  1     |  D03
476     |  785              |  0     |  NULL
1821    |  1234             |  0     |  E07
25951   |  1951             |  1     |  K73
```

How update my table to swap **Rate** and **Pid** values between lines having same customer_Id, so I can have a result like this:

```
--------------------------------------------
Id      |  Customer_Id      |  Rate  |  Pid
--------------------------------------------
180     |  374              |  0     |  NULL
277     |  374              |  1     |  A01
346     |  785              |  0     |  NULL
476     |  785              |  1     |  D03
1821    |  1234             |  0     |  E07
25951   |  1951             |  1     |  K73
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: swapping something sounds really strange operation for a database. Is that really what you're trying to accomplish, or is that just first step of trying to solve some other issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you *always* have *at most two* records per customer then you can use the following query:

```
SELECT ID,  Customer_Id, 
       CASE 
          -- 2 records per Customer_id -> swap
          WHEN COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY Customer_id) = 2 THEN
            CASE       
               WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Customer_id ORDER BY ID) = 1 
                  THEN LEAD(Rate) OVER (PARTITION BY Customer_id ORDER BY ID)
               ELSE LAG(Rate) OVER (PARTITION BY Customer_id ORDER BY ID)
            END
          -- 1 record per Customer_id -> don't swap
          ELSE Rate
       END,
       CASE 
          WHEN COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY Customer_id) = 2 THEN
            CASE       
               WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Customer_id ORDER BY ID) = 1 
                  THEN LEAD(Pid) OVER (PARTITION BY Customer_id ORDER BY ID)
               ELSE LAG(Pid) OVER (PARTITION BY Customer_id ORDER BY ID)
            END
          ELSE Pid
       END
FROM Sales
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/f1f62/1)

**Edit:**

If you want to `UPDATE` then you can wrap the above query in a `CTE` and do the update on the `CTE`:

```
;WITH ToUpdate AS (
SELECT ID,  Customer_Id, Rate, Pid, 
       COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY Customer_id) AS cnt,
       CASE       
         WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Customer_id ORDER BY ID) = 1 
           THEN LEAD(Rate) OVER (PARTITION BY Customer_id ORDER BY ID)
         ELSE LAG(Rate) OVER (PARTITION BY Customer_id ORDER BY ID)
       END AS NewRate,
       CASE       
         WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Customer_id ORDER BY ID) = 1 
           THEN LEAD(Pid) OVER (PARTITION BY Customer_id ORDER BY ID)
         ELSE LAG(Pid) OVER (PARTITION BY Customer_id ORDER BY ID)
       END AS NewPid
FROM Sales)
UPDATE ToUpdate
SET Rate = NewRate, Pid = NewPid
WHERE cnt = 2
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/d73dcb/1)

Answer (score 0):

This will do it, with the caveat that you have at most only two records with the same Customer_Id...

```
update Sales 
set Rate = 
    (
        select Rate from Sales sls 
        where sls.Customer_Id = Sales.Customer_Id 
             and sls.Rate <> Sales.Rate
    )
```